# Google Service Account Limit

Tags: google-oauth, google-analytics-api

We built a system where we can access all our clients google analytics. I use Google service accounts to do server calls to [google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide) and grant access to that [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) as a user. Some how there is a limitation where each service account reaches a limit to be added in user accounts. (we have more than 2000 clients).

As of now, I am creating multiple service accounts when ever the previous reaches its limit. What is the solution for this?

Thank You,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use Google Analytics from a management perspective

Comment: I am a developer and the issue i am facing right now is google did not specify any limit on how many times a service account can be added. Sometimes its 500,, sometimes its 99, and it could be any number. I would like to know if this can be avoided (by paying or configuring).

Comment: This question is programming related its related to the Google Analytics API not Google Analytics Application.

Answer (score 1):

The [Core Reporting API has a quota limit of of 10,000 requests per view (profile) per day](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas?hl=da#core_reporting).

I suspect what you are doing is trying to display your Google Analytics data to all of your customers.   Which isnt really going to work because of the quoat limit.  I recomend that you use your service account to download your data into your own system and then display the stored data to your users.

There is no way to increase this quota limit.